# $d,e$ be metrices on $X$ , under what condition(s) the function $g:X \times X \to \mathbb R $ , $g(x,y):=\min \{d(x,y),e(x,y)\}$ , is a metric ?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $d,e$ be metrices on a set $X$ , then under what condition(s)  the function $g:X \times X \to \mathbb R $  defined by $g(x,y):=\min \{d(x,y),e(x,y)\}$ , is a metric ?

Comment: Do you recall the axioms that a metric must satisfy?

Comment: @izœc: yes ....

Comment: Ok - for example, the first is that $g(x,x) = 0$ for all $x\in X$. Do you know how you might show that [if you know that $d, e$ are metrics as well]?

Comment: @izœc: $g(x,x)$ is always zero  if $d,e$ are known to be metrices , I already checked those trivial things my friend , also the symmetry .... the only thing troublesome is triangle inequality ...

Comment: Okay, well that is tricky.. in general it is not true (I think that there is a discussion of that here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584155/minimum-of-two-metrics-is-metric).

Comment: However, you ask what conditions we can place that force $g$ to be a metric... it is clear that if $d = e$ we have that $g$ is a metric. I am considering whether any other weaker condition will have the same result.

Comment: Well an obvious weaker condition, which causes $g$ to be a metric is $e(x,y)\geq d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$ (or $\leq$).

Comment: @izœc: $g(x,x)=\min \{d(x,x),e(x,x) \}=\min \{0,0 \}=0$ ; $g(x,y)=\min \{d(x,y),e(y,x) \}=\min \{d(y,x),e(y,x)\}=g(y,x)$ , am I wrong ???

Comment: @SouvikDey No, what you have there is correct.

Comment: @Dan That is true of course; I was trying to think if there was something weaker in the sense of the condition not even being a global relation between the two $e$ and $d$.